# Declaration char* not working with strcat()

Tags: c

This code compiles without errors, but upon opening the app, it says:

> file.exe has stopped working

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char *a = 'Hello';
  char *b = 'World';
  strcat(a,b);
  puts(a);
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You can't concatenate to a constant read-only string, which is exactly what `a` points to. And are those *really* single quotes around those words ?

Comment: @WhozCraig so what should I do?

Comment: strings are delimited by ", not '. Constant strings are not modifiable, you can't concatenate anything in a.

Comment: `'Hello'` should be `"Hello"`. That won't fix the problem, but it's important to get the fundamental distinction between a `char` literal (i.e., `'a'`) and a `char` array (i.e., `"abcd"`). `'Hello'` is a multibyte character literal; you don't want that, every.

Comment: The chapter about strings in your beginner-level C programming book might hold all the answers. Contrary to popular belief, SO isn't an interactive beginner-tutorial, nor a replacement for studies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate sufficient space and use double quote instead of single quote. You could use array.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char a[20] = "Hello";
  char b[10] = "World";
  strcat(a,b);
  puts(a);
}
```

Comment: const can be copied to non-const

Comment: @user463035818 -- yes, `"Hello"` is a `const`. But it's being **copied** into `a`, and `a` and the contents of `a` can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Constant strings are not modifiable. This is a proper way to declare, initialize and modify a string buffer in C:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   char a[20];
   char *b = "World";
   strcpy(a,"Hello");
   strcat(a,b);
   puts(a);
   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do strcat on pointer of characters. You only can do strcat on array of characters .... Sorry for my precedent answer, look at the code below :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   char a [20];
   char b[20];
   strcpy(a,"Hello");
   strcpy(b,"World");
   strcat(a,b);
   puts(a);
   return(0);
}
```